# Using 'ever since' with past perfect continuous tense

Tags: tense, past-perfect-continuous

So, I am trying to help my friend with his novel. It is completely written using the past tense. I need help from you to check if the following sentence is correct.

> As luck would have it, they all ended up getting jobs in the same city. Together, they rented a two-bedroom house and **had been living** there ever since.

I am trying to keep everything in the past. So, is it okay if I use past perfect continuous tense for the last part with 'ever since'?

Comment: Yes, it's fine.

Comment: It seems OK to me as long as you say, almost immediately, "Until that fateful day..." or "But then, after an argument, two of them moved out." The use of 'had' needs resolving quickly. What's the next line?

Comment: @Faj If you have a single question about the English language, please get answers in the answer section. Please do not use the comment section as a writing clinic. Comments are for notes and questions about the question itself.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137761/discussion-on-question-by-faj-using-ever-since-with-past-perfect-continuous-te).

Comment: As for resolution, this sentence could be a segue to an episode of some kind (e.g. "until that fateful day" as suggested above) or the story could end on that line. What would be odd is a return to the time of the original house renting.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't read correctly. "Had been living there ever since" in isolation is fine, but the whole thing reads badly because the tenses don't match throughout.

Ideally, it should say:

> As luck would have it, they **had all got** jobs in the same city. Together, they rented a two-bedroom house and **had been** living there ever since.

When you say that the whole novel is in the past tense, you still have to remember that the narrator is speaking as if they are in the present, recounting the past. When you say "they all ended up getting jobs in the city" it sounds like you are finishing up the anecdote and bringing the reader up the present, so it feels like you should be saying "they *have been* living there ever since", which would mean that they were still living there until *now* (the present).

Comment: A, B, C and D had known each other since childhood. They went to the same school, and even though they attended different colleges, they remained thick friends. As luck would have it, they all ended up getting jobs in the same city after their graduation. Then they rented a two-bedroom house together and started their professional journey three years ago....I changed the para a little bit. How is it now??

Comment: @Faj Great! Just two unrelated things to consider - 'thick friends' is a slightly outdated expression. I don't hear it much these days. 'Thick' can also mean *stupid*. 'Firm friends' is one alternative. Also, saying "three years ago" requires a date-stamp on the narrative. You might say when the events occurred, but unless you know what year the narrator is relating this from, "three years ago" means nothing. It's not wrong, just something to consider. What time period will the narrative cover? Will more than 3 years have passed by the end of the story?

Comment: A, B, C and D had known each other since childhood. They went to the same school, and even though they attended different colleges, they remained firm friends. As luck would have it, they all ended up getting jobs in the same city after their graduation. Then they rented a two-bedroom house together and started their professional journey together.....what about this?? Thanks for your kind help, btw....

Comment: @faj sounds good.

Comment: What if I write the para in past perfect...for example,                                            'A, B, C and D had known each other since childhood. They had gone to the same school, and even though they had attended different colleges, they had remained firm friends. As luck would have it, they had all ended up getting jobs in the same city after their graduation. Then they had rented a two-bedroom house together and had started their professional journey together'...    How does that sound?

Comment: Can someone please check my last comment and see if it is good to go?

Comment: @Faj:  That is grammatical but an overuse of the past perfect. It is not a change for the better.

Answer (score -1):

OP writes:

> *I am trying to keep everything in the past.* So, is it okay if I use past perfect continuous tense for the last part with 'ever since'? [my emphasis]

The past-perfect continuous **had been living** with **ever since** in that sentence is a kind of "fast-forward". It moves the temporal focus  to a point-in-time subsequent to the rental of the apartment but still in the past.

P.S. If you had written "*have* been living there ever since" it would be a fast-forward to a fictional present. Time-shifts of various kinds are normal in fiction.